# Back button returns to tags screen instead of search results

Tags: bug, android-app

When searching tags and clicking on one of the search results, if you click back you should go back to the search results but the app returns you to the tag selection screen. 
This makes searching navigation very frustrating.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: Redmi Note 3

  - OS Version: 5.1.1 (V8.0.6.0.LHOMIDG)